# selenium java handling windows dialog box

Tags: java, selenium, dialog, window, box

I am working on a project to automate a particular web portal data entry. Currently, facing issue with Window Dialog Box - not able to select and click a particular element on the window dialog box using selenium java. I also tried ROBOT framework - but once the window dialog box is active my keyboard functions does not work for that dialog box. Can anyone help? Within the organization, I am not allowed to download AutoIT for automating windows dialogue box. Can you please suggest any alternative or, any other alternate solution ?

Comment: I haven't done this, but have to looked into using CodedUI to interact with the Window Dialog Box?

Comment: I advise you to try Selenide framework, it should helps you with this issue, there several methods for this purposes, such as: download() and uploadFile(File…). More info you could find in documentation in official web-page: http://selenide.org/documentation.html